# Join similar observations within a data.frame with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to mix several observations in a data.frame using as a reference one constantly repeated variable.

Example:

```
id  var1    var2    var3
a   1   na  na
a   na  2   na
a   na  na  3
b   1       na
b   na  2   na
b   na  na  na
c   na  na  3
c   na  2   na
c   1   na  na
```

Expected result:

```
id  var1    var2    var3
a   1   2   3
b   1   2   na
c   1   2   3
```

Comment: are those literal `"na"` strings, or are those R's `NA`s? Is there literally an empty string in the first row of `b`, in `var2`, or did you miss that typing in the data? It might be helpful to give you sample data as something less ambiguous but pasting the output from `dput(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution (replacing "na" by `NA` with `na_if`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  na_if("na") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize(across(var1:var3, ~ sort(.x)[1]))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   id    var1  var2  var3 
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     1     2     3    
#> 2 b     1     2     <NA> 
#> 3 c     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- `"na"` above is really R's native `NA` (not a string);
- `b`'s first row, `var2` should be `NA` instead of an empty string `""`
- perhaps from the above, `var1:var3` should be numbers
- either you will never have a group where there is more than one non-`NA` in a group/column, or you don't care about anything other than the first and want the remaining discarded

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), ~ na.omit(.)[1]))
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   id     var1  var2  var3
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 a         1     2     3
# 2 b         1     2    NA
# 3 c         1     2     3
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"), var1 = c(1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), var2 = c(NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 2L, NA), var3 = c(NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA, NA, 3L, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data has `NA`, you can use the following `base R` option using the Data from @r2evans (thanks!):

```
aggregate(.~id, dat, mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action=NULL)
```

Output:

```
  id var1 var2 var3
1  a    1    2    3
2  b    1    2  NaN
3  c    1    2    3
```